# Examples about one of two probabilities of committing two type error may be equal to zero.

Tags: probability, statistics

Could you please show some examples that in a test of a statistical hypothesis, one of two probabilities of committing two type errors may be equal to zero.

Comment: You could have a test that always rejects the null hypothesis or a test that always fails to reject the null hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=1$ and $X_1$ is a sample of size 1 with two possible distributions: either 
$H_0:$ $X_1\sim \mathcal N_{0,1}$ -- standard normal distribution
or
$H_a:$ $X_1\sim E_1$ - exponential distribution.

Then a test with the critical region $\{X_1>0\}$ has type-$1$ error $$\alpha_1=\mathbb P_{H_0}(X_1>0)=\dfrac12$$ and type-$2$ error $$\alpha_2=\mathbb P_{H_a}(X_1\leq 0)=0.$$

There is a huge number of various examples for the case that you need. It will be better to specify, what kind of example do you search and what are your difficulties in building the required examples.